# macOS Sierra: reload firewall whenever network changes

Tags: networking, firewall, sudo, macos-sierra, launchctl

I've been trying to reload pf rules whenever network changes.
Here is my plist file. /Library/LaunchAgents/com.wwk.networkchange.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.wwk.networkchange</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sudo /sbin/pfctl -f /Users/wwk/pf.conf</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/private/var/run/resolv.conf</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I can see that /private/var/run/resolv.conf is changed when network interfaces are changed but pf rules aren't reloaded at all.
FYI, /Users/wwk/pf.conf is there and I've enabled /sbin/pfctl to do without password prompt via /etc/sudoers file.
Thanks in any advance!

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two problems.

First, your `ProgramArguments` needs to be an array of strings, rather than a single string with spaces.

Second, you really shouldn't use `sudo` for this -- just make this a LaunchDaemon (which runs as root) instead of a LaunchAgent (which runs as the logged in user). Thus, your `ProgramArguments` should look like this:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/sbin/pfctl</string>
    <string>-f</string>
    <string>/Users/wwk/pf.conf</string>
</array>
```

Comment: You're right regarding ProgramArguments. I've arranged them as you pointed but still no luck.
Regarding sudo issue, I see that I still have to prefix with sudo even though it's registered as sudoers.

Comment: @Pei Did you move it to /Library/LaunchDaemons (& then either reboot or load it with `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.wwk.networkchange.plist`)? That should make `sudo` irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah, I did so and did sudo launchctl load/unload several times but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was because my new daemon was conflicted with Apple's default pfctl daemon.
So I've had to update the default pfctl daemon plist to watch paths which are changed whenever network changes.
Add following to the `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist`

```
<WatchPaths>
<array>
    <string>/private/var/run/resolv.conf</string>
    <string>/etc/pf.conf</string>
    <string>/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist</string>
    <string>/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist</string>
</array>
```

Btw, we have to enable changes in system files by `$ csrutil disable` in macOS recovery mode to make changes in above plist file. (should do `$ csrutil enable` after necessary changes in system files)